# Tooltip for column titles in matrix

Tags: powerbi

I want to add a description to titles of columns in a matrix ([Image of matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqF9q.png))

For instance, when I hover over France, I want to display Europe. When I hover over Canada, I want to display North America, and so on. In my data I have a column named continent. Using a tooltip, I managed to display the description over data in the matrix. For instance, when I hover over 8587, it displays Europe.

Is there a way that I can display a particular continent when I hover over the country?